How to use ffmpeg to open 2 cams and push the stream from one of them?
I'm using ffmpeg to capture 2 cams and push stream from one of them.
For single camera, I start capturing frames by calling startCameraCapture() from main() which calls initRemoteStream(). Here it opens a pipe to ffmpeg to initialize streaming. Followed by it, decodePacket() is called which writes YUV422 data to the pipe. It runs fine.
But when I want to use 2 cameras, I create a thread for each camera in main() and define active_cam. When I want to push cam1's stream, active_cam = 1. The same logic of the single cam is used. It doesn't work.
Could you please help to understand the logic? Following is my C++ code. Thanks.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
}

// 定义全局变量
std::queue<cv::Mat> frame_queue1, frame_queue2;
std::mutex queue_mutex1, queue_mutex2;
std::condition_variable cv1, cv2;
std::atomic<bool> keep_running(true);
FILE* pipe_s1 = nullptr;
FILE* pipe_s2 = nullptr;

// 初始化推流
FILE* initRemoteStream(int camera_id) {
    std::string ffmpegCmd = "ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422 -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -i - -vf scale 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.66.126/live/stream" + std::to_string(camera_id);
    FILE* pipe_s = popen(ffmpegCmd.c_str(), "w");
    if (!pipe_s) {
        std::cerr << "无法启动 FFmpeg 进程" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    return pipe_s;
}

// 解码数据包
bool decodePacket(AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, AVPacket *packet, int video_stream_index, cv::Mat& global_frame, std::queue<cv::Mat>& frame_queue, std::condition_variable& cv) {
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    int ret;

    if (packet->stream_index == video_stream_index) {
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(codec_ctx, packet);
        if (ret < 0) return false;

        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret < 0) return false;

        int width = codec_ctx->width;
        int height = codec_ctx->height;

        // 创建 YUV422 格式的 Mat 对象
        cv::Mat yuv422_img(height, width, CV_8UC2, frame->data[0]);

        // 将 YUV422 转换为 BGR
        //cv::cvtColor(yuv422_img, global_frame, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2);
        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex1);
            frame_queue.push(global_frame.clone());
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }

    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return true;
}


// 摄像头捕获线程
void startCameraCapture(const char* device_name, int camera_id) {
    AVFormatContext *format_ctx = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = nullptr;
    const AVCodec *codec = nullptr;
    AVPacket packet;
    int video_stream_index = -1;

    avdevice_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    AVDictionary *options = nullptr;
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
    AVInputFormat *input_format = av_find_input_format("v4l2");

    if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, device_name, input_format, &options) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "无法打开输入" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, nullptr) < 0) return;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    AVCodecParameters *codec_par = format_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar;
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_par->codec_id);
    codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, codec_par);
    avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, nullptr);

    // 初始化推流
    FILE* pipe_s = initRemoteStream(camera_id);
    if (camera_id == 1) {
        pipe_s1 = pipe_s;
    } else {
        pipe_s2 = pipe_s;
    }

    while (keep_running) {
        if (av_read_frame(format_ctx, &packet) >= 0) {
            cv::Mat global_frame;
            if (decodePacket(codec_ctx, &packet, video_stream_index, global_frame, (camera_id == 1 ? frame_queue1 : frame_queue2), (camera_id == 1 ? cv1 : cv2))) {
                av_packet_unref(&packet);
            }
        }
    }

    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
    pclose(pipe_s);
}

// 推理线程
void inferenceThread() {
    while (keep_running) {
        cv::Mat frame1, frame2;

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex1);
            cv1.wait(lock, [] { return !frame_queue1.empty(); });
            frame1 = frame_queue1.front();
            frame_queue1.pop();
        }

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex2);
            cv2.wait(lock, [] { return !frame_queue2.empty(); });
            frame2 = frame_queue2.front();
            frame_queue2.pop();
        }

        // 进行推理处理 

        // 根据CAN信号决定推流
        int selected_camera_id = 1; // 假设根据CAN信号确定的摄像头ID
        FILE* selected_pipe_s = (selected_camera_id == 1) ? pipe_s1 : pipe_s2; // 选择相应的推流管道

        if (selected_pipe_s) {
            fwrite(selected_camera_id == 1 ? frame1.data : frame2.data, 1, (selected_camera_id == 1 ? frame1.total() : frame2.total()) * frame1.elemSize(), selected_pipe_s);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::thread camera1(startCameraCapture, "/dev/video0", 1);
    std::thread camera2(startCameraCapture, "/dev/video1", 2);
    std::thread infer_thread(inferenceThread);

    camera1.join();
    camera2.join();
    infer_thread.join();

    // 释放资源
    if (pipe_s1) pclose(pipe_s1);
    if (pipe_s2) pclose(pipe_s2);

    return 0;
}



What doesn't work?

BTW you don't seem to be checking if the returned FILE* from initRemoteStream is nullptr. Add some logs in your code especially for error conditions.

you are starting remote stream for both cameras. I think one of them will not work properly. You may need to start it only once and manipulate with frames from inference thread
